# With ExpressJS, how can I utilize an NPM package on the client-side?

Tags: node.js, express, pixi.js

I've been exploring JavaScript game development utilizing the HTML canvas and Socket.io, and I just came across the canvas framework PixiJS.

I decided to try it out, so I started a new project and npm install-ed express, socket.io and pixi.js. I did a typical express and socketio static server, serving '/public'

'./index.js:'

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server)

app.use(express.static('public'))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} connected!`)

  socket.once('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} disconnect!`)
  })
})


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`)
})
```

But then it hit me, on the client-side JavaScript I can't access the pixi.js package. I don't even really know where to start to utilize the framework client-side. Here's how it's supposed to work:

'./public/js/main.js'

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
const app = new PIXI.Application()
document.body.appendChild(app.view)
```

But obviously I get 'Failed to resolve module specifier....' because it's a server-side package.

I'm super new to HTTP servers and full-stack development, how do I go about utilizing an NPM package on an express-served client directory? I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/), ...

These basically compile your code and dependencies (usually to an older version of JS for browser-compatibility) and bundles them together, giving you (by default) a single `.js` file that includes your (used) dependencies. This works for most modules.

The [GitHub for pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs) also specifies a CDN install you can use instead. If this is the only dependency you care about, that would be an easier approach.